# Why MySQL drivers/clients like MySQLdb or mysqlclient or PyMySQL considered Blocking even when used in Async Web Frameworks like Tornado?

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, tornado, mysql-python

In async web frameworks like Tornado, we can do non-blocking calls using its @gen.coroutine or @tornado.web.asynchronous decorators. For example we can do non-blocking or async calls by using the AsyncHTTPClient module.

So we can use it either by using @gen.coroutine decorator along with the "yield" keyword, like "yield tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url)"  or by using a callback function with @tornado.web.asynchronous. For both of the methods, it works as non-blocking.

Similarly, then why can't it be done the same way for Python's MySQL drivers/clients like MySQLdb, PyMySQL, mysqlclient etc. I mean why can't these drivers be used similarly to how AsyncHTTPClient is used along with either gen.coroutine or callback via web.asynchronous decorators. Why can't the drivers be used with gen.coroutine or web.asynchronous to make the calls non-blocking?

What are the reasons that stop them from being asynchronous, I mean how AsyncHTTPClient is non-blocking but MySQLdb.connect, MySQLdb.connect().cursor.query(), etc are not?

Also I know there are few async Tornado specific MySQL drivers/clients like TorMySQL, Tornado-MySQL (by PyMySQL), asynctorndb, etc. But why can't the normal drivers/clients like mysqlclient or MySQLdb be used directly as non-blocking, or what are the changes made in TorMySQL, Tornado-MySQL (by PyMySQL) that they are defined as async mysql drivers/clients for Tornado?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say that Tornado is an asynchronous framework, this is a *requirement* rather than an *effect*. To use Tornado effectively, anything you do that is expensive needs to be asynchronous; Tornado cannot magically make synchronous code asynchronous. This means you need to either choose asynchronous libraries which are compatible with Tornado, or run expensive blocking operations in another thread.

See the [introduction to asynchronous I/O in the Tornado User's guide](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Ben, although I know about what you said already, what my real question is why MySQL drivers/clients are blocking and not The AsyncHTTPClient modules, what goes under the hood that there is a difference in these two modules? I mean what exactly happens, the control-flow and everything, this is what I want to know.

Comment: Everything is synchronous unless it goes out of its way to be asynchronous. Generally, asynchronous functions either take a callback argument or return a placeholder (like a Future) in place of their "real" result.

Comment: Exactly. Then why can't we do it with MySQLdb calls. What implementation is stopping it from utilizing the asynchronous callback style or even the coroutine style. I mean, why can't I use the MySQLdb calls to connect() to database, execute() query using gen.coroutine's  yield or by using a callback style of web.asynchronous . Why can't I do this with the MySQL calls and make it abide by the asynchronous rules of Tornado? What is exactly stopping it? What is the implementation that is becoming the problem in all this?

Comment: You'd need to add callback arguments (or `Future` return values) to all the `MySQLdb` functions *and all the network calls they use internally*. Once you've done that, it's no longer compatible with the old synchronous interface.

Comment: So it means, internally the MySQLdb modules have blocking calls, and the async libraries have basically hacked into it and changed these blocking calls to async by playing with the IOLoop and thus the async libraries can make non-blocking calls? Is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, MySQLdb has blocking calls. The async libraries probably aren't modifying MySQLdb, they are reimplementing the protocol from the ground up using asynchronous operations. But I'm not sure about these particular libraries.

Comment: Do you know about any specific async libraries? If yes, can you suggest some, I am asking this because you are one of the lead developers of Tornado, so you must have come across some libraries by now. Please suggest some.

Comment: No, I've never used any async libraries for mysql.

Comment: So how do you do it? What is the method you follow?

Comment: It's been years since I've used mysql with tornado.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So one last thing, is the code always asynchronous when used with web.asynchronous, even if I have not used any callback style? I mean, if a have  get() method with web.asynchronous decorator, and in the get() method I call another method, lets say do_something() of the same handler without a callback or something and return from get() method after processing the result from do_something()? Eg: [at]web.asynchronous \n def get(self): \n res=self.do_something() \n self.write(res)

Comment: The `asynchronous` decorator doesn't do any good unless you use callbacks. All it does is tell tornado that you may use callbacks so it doesn't automatically call `finish()` when `get()` returns.

Comment: Thanks! Ben. Was really helpful, everything. I have another question which I posted. If you find time, then please have a look. Having some doubts understanding them entirely.